# Execute stored procedure which should return int

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure which takes several input-parameters and returns an integer :

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[HB_ValidateLogin_HitAlacarte]
(
    @Login nvarchar(50),
    @Pwd nvarchar(50),
    @Vat int, 
    @Page  nvarchar(50)
)
as
Begin
    return -3 --- too many Badlogins 
End
```

I call this stored procedure using Entity Framework :

```
try
{
    string sqlQuery = "exec [dbo].[HB_ValidateLogin_HitAlacarte] @Login, @Pwd, @Vat, @Page";

    var outParam = new SqlParameter();
    outParam.ParameterName = "@return_value";
    outParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.BigInt;
    outParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

    SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Login",  Value =initRequest.Login, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input},
        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Pwd",  Value =initRequest.Pwd, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input },
        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Vat",  Value =initRequest.VatNumber, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input},
        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Page",  Value =initRequest.Page, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input},
        outParam
    };

    using (xmlALaCarteContext)
    {
        List<List<int>> result = xmlALaCarteContext.Database.SqlQuery<List<int>>(sqlQuery, sqlParams).ToList();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

however when I run the code, I never get the -3. My outParam always has a value of null. What am I doing wrong? I am using EntityFramework Version 6.0.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your `@return_value` as an OUTPUT parameter in your stored procedure and then set it rather than calling RETURN

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[HB_ValidateLogin_HitAlacarte] (
    @Login nvarchar(50),
    @Pwd nvarchar(50),
    @Vat int, 
    @Page  nvarchar(50),
    @return_value int OUTPUT
)
```

or change your exec statement so it handles the return value but I am not sure of the right syntax to use with your framework but something like

```
string sqlQuery = "exec @return_value =[dbo].[HB_ValidateLogin_HitAlacarte]..."
```

Comment: There is no other way? There are other (older applications) which use the same stored procedure. So changing it, is not really an option.

Comment: What about my second suggestion?